# capture user leaving page with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a feature that if a user is navigating away from a page and they have unsaved changes on the page they get alerted. So I need to capture the event that fires to movement from the page and perform custom actions on it. Hoping to do this with jquery. Any tips?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do this with jQuery, but you can attach a handler to [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) with plain JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "You have unsaved changes, do you want to leave?";
};
```

Just bind this when they make changes to any inputs, and unbind it when hitting the save button (so it won't prompt on submission) with `window.onbeforeunload = null;`.

Comment: jQuery can handle the event with bind, but I'm not sure that it's normalized across browsers.

Comment: @zzzzBov - It *doesn't* work cross-browser...so it doesn't work :)

Comment: IE 8 considers null a a return submission, so it will fire the event with the default text anyway.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unload/
"The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers, and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event."